# .class ファイルに含まれる型情報を json などスクリプトで扱いやすい形式に変換するには？

Tags: java

java の .class ファイルは、 `javap`コマンドなどで型情報を取得できます。
スクリプトで処理を行いたいため、 javap で取得できるような情報を、 json や xml など、スクリプトで処理しやすい形に変換したいと考えています。

これを実現する方法はありますでしょうか。

---

(追記 9/11)

欲しいものは、コマンドラインから起動するツールです。誤解を与えてしまったらすいません。

イメージとしては、次のような java ファイルをコンパイルした .class ファイルがあったときに、

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private String name;

    HelloWorld(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld("Foo");
        helloWorld.hello();
    }
}
```

次のような出力をしてくれるツールです。

```
{
  "type": "class",
  "name": "HelloWorld",
  "visibility": "public",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "visibility": "private",
      "static": false
    }
  ],
  "methods": [
    {
      "name": "HelloWorld",
      "visibility": "package",
      "static": false,
      "args": [
        "java.lang.String"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "hello",
      "visibility": "public",
      "static": false,
      "args": [],
      "ret": "void"
    },
    {
      "name": "main",
      "visibility": "public",
      "static": true,
      "args": [
        "java.lang.String[]"
      ],
      "ret": "void"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: 「javapで取得できるような情報」として抽出したいのは具体的にどういう内容でしょうか。逆アセンブル結果？ メソッドのシグネチャ？ また処理としては任意のclassファイルをコマンドラインから解析することを想定されているのでしょうか。

Comment: @holywise 追記しました。逆アセンブルの結果ではなく、シグネチャです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javadocを出す仕組みをカスタマイズすることで実現できます。
http://argius.hatenablog.jp/entry/2014/01/07/222423

Docletを実装したクラスでは、例示していただいたJSONの内容にかなり近い、次のようなクラスをハンドリングできます。
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/MethodDoc.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/ClassDoc.html

Answer (score -4):

まずRuntime使ってcmd.exeを実行しそのコマンドとしてjavapを動かす
実行結果を文字列として受け取って、あとはDocumentBuilderとかElementクラスを使って書き出せば出来る気がする